# Blocks on Swift (animateWithDuration:animations:completion:)

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I'm having trouble making the blocks work on Swift. Here's an example that worked (without completion block):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.07) {
    self.someButton.alpha = 1
}
```

or alternatively without the trailing closure:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
    self.someButton.alpha = 1
})
```

but once I try to add the completion block it just won't work:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
    self.blurBg.alpha = 1
}, completion: {
    self.blurBg.hidden = true
})
```

The autocomplete gives me `completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?` but not sure how to make it work. Also tried with trailing closure but got the same error:

`! Could not find an overload for 'animateWithDuration that accepts the supplied arguments`

### Update for Swift 3 / 4:

```
// This is how I do regular animation blocks
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    <#code#>
}

// Or with a completion block
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    <#code#>
}, completion: { _ in
    <#code#>
})
```

I don't use the trailing closure for the completion block because I think it lacks clarity, but if you like it then you can see [Trevor's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915289/3713118).

Comment: "The autocomplete gives me completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? but not sure how to make it work" Exactly what it says. This must be a block that takes a Bool and returns a Void.

Comment: How do you know what the ((Bool) -> Void)? is for? Since I've used this in ObjC before I know it is BOOL finished. But how would a swift coder know?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The completion parameter in `animateWithDuration` takes a block which takes one boolean parameter. In Swift, like in Obj-C blocks, you must specify the parameters that a closure takes:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
    self.blurBg.alpha = 1
}, completion: {
    (value: Bool) in
    self.blurBg.hidden = true
})
```

The important part here is the `(value: Bool) in`. That tells the compiler that this closure takes a Bool labeled 'value' and returns Void.

For reference, if you wanted to write a closure that returned a Bool, the syntax would be

```
{(value: Bool) -> bool in
    //your stuff
}
```

Comment: Can also be solved by using `$0` for the first argument, just using the variable inside the block, the compiler figures out that your block accepts an argument.

Comment: dat completion block syntax :(

Answer (score 41):

The completion is correct, the closure must accept a `Bool` parameter: `(Bool) -> ()`. Try

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    self.blurBg.alpha = 1
}, completion: { finished in
    self.blurBg.hidden = true
})
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this version *is* correct. You don't need to write out the full type since it can be inferred, so all you need is just to mention the closure parameter as mentioned here.

Answer (score 32):

Underscore by itself alongside the `in` keyword will ignore the input

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
    self.blurBg.alpha = 1
}, completion: { _ in
    self.blurBg.hidden = true
})
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    self.blurBg.alpha = 1
}, completion: { _ in
    self.blurBg.isHidden = true
})
```

Answer (score 10):

There is my solution above based on accepted answer above. It fades out a view and hiddes it once almost invisible.

**Swift 2**

```
func animateOut(view:UIView) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration (0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear ,animations: {
        view.layer.opacity = 0.1
        }, completion: { _ in
            view.hidden = true
    })   
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
func animateOut(view: UIView) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear ,animations: {
        view.layer.opacity = 0.1
    }, completion: { _ in
        view.isHidden = true
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, this will compile

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
    self.blurBg.alpha = 1
}, completion: {(_) -> Void in
    self.blurBg.hidden = true
})
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.blurBg.alpha = 1
}, completion: {(_) -> Void in
    self.blurBg.isHidden = true
})
```

The reason I made the Bool area an underscore is because you not using that value, if you need it you can replace the (_) with (value : Bool)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you want to throw this in a variable to animate in different ways depending on the situation. For that you need

```
 let completionBlock : (Bool) -> () = { _ in 
 }
```

Or you could use the equally verbose:

```
 let completionBlock = { (_:Bool) in 
 }
```

But in any case, you have have to indicate the `Bool` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3.x + 4.x**

I'd like to make an update and simplify the things.

Example below is implemented in any `view` it is hiding slowly and when it is completely transparent; removes it self from parent `view`

`ok` variable  will always returns `true` with animation termination.

```
    alpha = 1
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0
    }) { (ok) in
        print("Ended \(ok)")
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```