# how to declare Swift C closures

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to use `animateWithDuration` closure in Swift. I have declared the arguments in the closure as mentioned in the Apple Book for Swift. However, I am still getting an error.

Below is the code snippet:

```
if(!isRotating){
 isRotating = true

 var myImageTemp :UIImageView  = self.myImage
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1, options: UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseOut, animations: 
{
() in myImageTemp.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle + M_PI_2)
},
 completion: 
{
(Bool finished) in self.pathAnimation() })

 }
```

It gives me an error:

> Could find an overload that accepts the supplied arguments.

And also it tells me:

> Implicit use of self in closure.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You code and question format is a bit messy. Please tidy it up - it will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blocks on Swift (animateWithDuration:animations:completion:)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071334/blocks-on-swift-animatewithdurationanimationscompletion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
    animations:
    {
        // your code.
    },
    completion:
    {
        (completed: Bool) in
        // your code.
    })
```

The `(completed: Bool) in` part indicates that the closure takes a Bool parameter labeled `completed`. If you are not interested in accessing the `completed` parameter, you can ignore it using an underscore.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, 
animations: 
    {
        // your code.
    }, 
    completion: 
    { _ in
        // your code.
    })
```

Comment: still unable to implement it properly. Still giving me an error :
could not find overload for animateWithDuration that accepts these arguments.