# issue with animate with duration in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I got an error while using blocks in animateWithDuration:animations:completion: method

below is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell=tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    var backGrndView:UIView?=cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as UIView?
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
        animations: {
            backGrndView?.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
        },
        completion: { finished in
            backGrndView?.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
    })
}
```

I tried the solutions at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071334/blocks-on-swift-animatewithdurationanimationscompletion).

But my problem is not solved.

below is screenshot:

[image]

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using swift 3?

Comment: @Cruz, I think I was.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that problem is the fact that swift auto returns if there is only one statement in closure. You can work around this by adding explicit returns:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2,
                           animations: {
                            backGrndView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                            return
},
                           completion: { finished in
                            backGrndView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                            return
})
```

This statement:

```
 backGrndView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

returns `()?` that is same as `Void?`, but closure return type is `Void`.