# Making a view fadeout in time if slider value isn't updated

Tags: swift, animation, fadeout

I'm working on a drawing app and when the user selects the brush size / color / opacity I'm making a small preview of the brush appear at the center of the screen. I would like to make it fade out after a few seconds if the value isn't updated. When I tried implementing like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071334/blocks-on-swift-animatewithdurationanimationscompletion), the preview doesn't reappear when a slider value is updated. I tried many things but can't seem to get it work. An extract of my code is below. Kindly let me know if you have any ideas of how I can do this.

**Slider Value Changed**

```
func colorDrawDidChange(sender:UISlider!) {
        if (sender.tag == 100) {
            self.red = CGFloat(sender.value)
        }
        else if (sender.tag == 101) {
            self.blue = CGFloat(sender.value)
        }
        else {
            self.green = CGFloat(sender.value)
        }
        drawPreview()
        animateOut(previewView)
    }
```

**Draw Preview View**

```
let previewView = UIImageView()

func drawPreview() {

        previewView.hidden = false
        previewView.alpha = 1.0
        previewView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,90,90)
        previewView.center = CGPoint(x: screenWidth/2,y: screenHeight/2)
        self.view.addSubview(previewView)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(previewView.frame.size)
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()


        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushWidth)

        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, opacity)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 45.0, 45.0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 45.0, 45.0)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
        previewView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    }
```

**Animate Out**

```
func animateOut(view1:UIView) {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
            view1.alpha = 1
            }, completion: {
                (value: Bool) in
                view1.hidden = true
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by calling the method when the user was done using the slider

```
sizeDrawSlider.addTarget(self, action: "removePreview", forControlEvents: (.TouchUpInside | .TouchUpOutside))
```