# Can't put transform change in animation block of animateWithDuration in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to change the transform of a layer inside of the animation block of a simple `animateWithDuration` call in Swift:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.05, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn , animations: {
            self.zigZag!.layer.mask.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 0)
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        })
```

However, this always presents me with the following build error:

```
Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type '(Double, animations: () -> Void)'
```

If I delete the trasnform line or replace it with something else like this:

```
self.zigZag!.center = self.view.center
```

Then the build error goes away and the app builds just fine.

At this point I'm not sure how I'm supposed to change the transform inside the animation block and get this to build properly.

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071334/blocks-on-swift-animatewithdurationanimationscompletion hope it helps you

Comment: @AshishKakkad I just tried all of the answers on the linked page and none of them make a difference.

Comment: I hope the answer will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could omit the `Void -> in` altogether in your case; the real culprit that is causing the problem is this line:

```
self.zigZag!.layer.mask.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 0)
```

because there is a type mismatch.

It should be:

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.05, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
   self.view!.layer.mask.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
}, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.05, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.view!.layer.mask.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(100.0, 0.0, 0.0)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help you were right this fixed it!