# How to add a completion to an animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

Hey I want to create a set game app, and now I want my cards(UIViews) move to a newPosition. after the animation ended I want this view to remove from super view

```
   func btnUp(card: CardSubview, frame: CGRect) {

        let newPosition = CGRect(x: (self.superview?.frame.minX)!, y: (self.superview?.frame.maxY)!, width: card.bounds.width, height: card.bounds.height)
        //UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {card.frame = newPosition})
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {card.frame = newPosition}, completion: {if card.frame == newPosition {card.removeFromSuperview()}})

    }
```

this is working but If I want to add a completion I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type
>   '((Bool) -> Void)?'**

so what am I doin wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blocks on Swift (animateWithDuration:animations:completion:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071334/blocks-on-swift-animatewithdurationanimationscompletion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration) says:

> **completion**
>
> A block object to be executed when the animation sequence ends. This
> block has no return value and takes a single Boolean argument that
> indicates whether or not the animations actually finished before the
> completion handler was called.

So you need to give that boolean argument to completion handler:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {card.frame = newPosition}, completion: { finish in
    if card.frame == newPosition {
         card.removeFromSuperview()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You need to set `completion block` variable

```
func btnUp(card: CardSubview, frame: CGRect) {

    let newPosition = CGRect(x: (self.superview?.frame.minX)!, y: (self.superview?.frame.maxY)!, width: card.bounds.width, height: card.bounds.height)
    //UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {card.frame = newPosition})
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
        card.frame = newPosition
        }, completion: { finish in
             if card.frame == newPosition {card.removeFromSuperview()

        }})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
   view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: view.frame.maxX, y: 0)
},completion:{(completed:Bool) in
   if(completed){view.removeFromSuperview()}
})
```